# singleton thread safety in Java

Tags: java, android, multithreading

Basically i was going trough a multithreading guide in developers.android.com when i saw something that confused me...(i am reffering to this article

http://developer.android.com/training/multiple-threads/create-threadpool.html

)

In the Define the Thread Pool Class section where they mention that the class should have a private constructor in order to make it singleton, the writer claims that by doing this the code would not require synhronization. I am confused why this is thread safe, as altough it is a singleton it can still be referenced by multiple threads simultaneously causing memory consistency errors etc.

Comment: Could you please clarify your question and include the relevant parts of the article here?

Comment: I must be missing something... I know that it is the same everywhere - but so what. Two different threads can still modify its state at the same time and you undoubtedly know that this is a problem. For example : I define a singleton class : SingletonExample.
it has one integer field : int value = 0;
Two threads can still modify value at once due to it not being synchronized am I right ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What they mean is:

- Since the constructor is private only a method inside the class itself may create an instance of that class
- The only instance of that class created is through:

  ```
  static  
  {
        // Creates a single static instance of PhotoManager
         sInstance = new PhotoManager();
  }
  ```
- The static { ... } block is thread safe because it is executed by the class loader, which is synchronized

Comment: The last bullet is what really answers the question, but great data all around

Comment: "Which is synchronized" Wheres the source/specification for this?

Comment: Not sure where the Android specific specs are but these articles talks about this:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-5.html
http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-dclp4/index.html

Comment: @Maxaon3000 Thanks; ended up finding it in the language spec too (chapter 8). Can't find the Dalvik VM specifications (found the architecture, but doesn't give information to the extent of the JLS), so I guess JVMS will have to do